# Parsing a file for an Android device

Tags: java, parsing, android

I am trying to parse `InputEvent`s of an Android device.

> **Background:**
>
> - For an android device we have a utility `getevent` which gives all the touch events that are sent to a device.
> - `getevent -l` gives all the input events to the device.
> - Every event has **3** fields - `EVENT_TYPE`, `EVENT_CODE` and `VALUE`.
> - `EVENT_TYPE` can be of following types - `EV_KEY`, `EV_ABS` and `EV_SYN`.
> - In turn, each `EVENT_TYPE` can have different `EVENT_CODES`. 
>     ***For e.g.***
>     
>     `EV_KEY` --> `BTN_TOUCH`
>     `EV_ABS` --> `ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y` and 
>     `EV_SYN` --> `SYN_MT_REPORT, SYN_REPORT`
> - And every `EVENT_CODE` can have a `VALUE`.
> - Every event is separated by a `SYN_REPORT`.
> - Each event can itself be a multi touch event be separated by a `SYN_MT_REPORT`.
> - Every touch starts with a `EV_KEY - BTN_TOUCH - DOWN` and ends with a `EV_KEY - BTN_TOUCH - UP` combination. (There are event separators after `EV_KEY - BTN_TOUCH - UP` viz. `SYN_MT_REPORT` and `SYN_REPORT`, but they are not important.

More description: [Event Types](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt) and [Multi Touch events](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt)

---

> ```
> EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN     <--------------
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011               |
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000               |
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c               |---First event,
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4               |   with DOWN and only
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000               |   1 finger touched.
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000 <--------------
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011 <--------------
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000 <-------      | 
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c        |      | 
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4   Finger 1    | 
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000 <-------      | 
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013               |---Second event
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001 <-------      |   with 2 mutitouch events
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076        |      | 
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e   Finger 2    | 
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000 <-------      |         
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000 <--------------
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011 <--------------  
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000 <-------      |  
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000190        |      |  
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000035d   Finger 1    |  
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000 <-------      |  
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013               |  
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001 <-------      |   
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000f8        |      |   
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000003cf   Finger 2    |---Third event
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000 <-------      |   with 3 mulittouch events  
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015               |
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002 <-------      |  
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000251        |      |  
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000310   Finger 3    |  
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000 <-------      |          
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000 <--------------  
> EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            UP       <--------------  
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000               |---Final Event,  
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000 <--------------   only 1 finger
> ```

---

An example of actual input is:

> ```
> EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN                
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001a3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001a3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001a3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001a3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001a3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001a3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001a3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000011c            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001f4            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000076            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000001cd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000001a3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000014b            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000026e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000b7            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002ef            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000209            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000225            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000015f            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002a1            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000c7            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000319            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000021e            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000258            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000167            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002cc            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000d4            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000339            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000228            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000027d            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000016f            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002ed            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000dd            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000035e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000231            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002a1            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000178            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000030f            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000e4            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000037d            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000023a            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002c2            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000182            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000329            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000eb            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000039b            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000242            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002de            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000018a            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000343            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000ef            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000003b3            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000247            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000002f6            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000018e            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000354            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000f3            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000003c2            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000024d            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000306            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000018f            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000035c            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000f5            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000003cb            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000024f            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000030e            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000011            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000190            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000035d            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000013            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000001            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000000f8            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    000003cf            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000015            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000002            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000251            
> EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00000310            
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
> EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            UP                  
> EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000            
> EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
> ```

---

This is how I am trying to parse it:

```java
package com.xolo;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public Main() {

    }

    public void readFile() {
        File file = new File("....../output2.txt");
        List<Event> listOfEvents = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
            listOfEvents = createEvents(is);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (listOfEvents == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (Event event : listOfEvents) {
            System.out.println(event.toString());
        }
    }

    private List<Event> createEvents(BufferedReader is) {
        List<Event> listOfEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        Event event = null;
        String[] tokens;
        try {
            while (true) {
                tokens = is.readLine().split("\\s+");
                if (tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("BTN_TOUCH")) {
                    if (tokens[2].equalsIgnoreCase("DOWN")) {
                        event = new Event();
                        continue;
                    } else if (tokens[2].equalsIgnoreCase("UP")) {
                        tokens = is.readLine().split("\\s+");
                        if (tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("SYN_MT_REPORT")) {
                            tokens = is.readLine().split("\\s+");
                            if (tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("SYN_REPORT")) {
                                return listOfEvents;
                            } else {
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                        }
                    }
                } else if (tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR")) {
                    event.mtEvents.add(createMTEvent(is));
                } else if (tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("SYN_REPORT")) {
                    if (event == null) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }
                    listOfEvents.add(event);
                    event = new Event();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private MTEvent createMTEvent(BufferedReader is) {
        String[] tokens;
        try {
            tokens = is.readLine().split("\\s+");
            if (!tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            int id = Integer.valueOf(tokens[2]);

            tokens = is.readLine().split("\\s+");
            if (!tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("ABS_MT_POSITION_X")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            int x = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2], 16);

            tokens = is.readLine().split("\\s+");
            if (!tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("ABS_MT_POSITION_Y")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            int y = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2], 16);

            tokens = is.readLine().split("\\s+");
            if (!tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("SYN_MT_REPORT")) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            return new MTEvent(id, x, y);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main mn = new Main();
        mn.readFile();
    }

    private class MTEvent {
        int trackingID;
        int x;
        int y;

        public MTEvent(int id, int x, int y) {
            this.trackingID = id;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ID: " + trackingID + ", x: " + x + ", y: " + y;
        }
    }

    private class Event {
        List<MTEvent> mtEvents;

        Event() {
            mtEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("Event: \n");
            for (MTEvent mtEvent : mtEvents) {
                stringBuilder.append(mtEvent.toString()).append("\n");
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to separate the individual event and MultiTouch event into separate methods but I don't think I have done it right.

There are a number of things that I want to correct:

- The parsing logic itself.
- The Exceptions thrown (any different way to do it?)
- The splitting of `input` on `space` characters (any better way to do it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Naming

The first point i'd like to raise is the naming of your class i.e. `Main`. This isn't very descriptive of what your intention is. I'd expect a class like `AndroidTouchInputEventsReader` that contains a method such as  `List<Event> parseAndroidTouchEvents(BufferedReader);`.  Try to think in terms of another programmer using the code, and attempt to make it clear how to use your methods.

```
class Main -> lets rename this AndroidTouchInputEventsReader
readFile() -> lets change this to List<Event> parseAndroidTouchEvents(BufferedReader)
```

Then, external to this class we can handle creation of a `BufferedReader` which could come from a file or in fact any `InputStream`.

## Data

The classes `Event` being private to the `Main` class will hide the implementation to the Users. Currently that's OK as you're only printing the Events to the console, but if you think of your class as a way of getting `InputEvents` in a different part of your program this won't work. In order for the next step to work, I would enable an MTEvent to be updated using setter methods, so I would add `set`

## Parsing

Firstly, I agree with you splitting your lines on spaces. This certainly fits the file format. I would like to have seen you decouple the reading of the file to the parsing of the lines.

A standard way of dealing with parsing a sequence of things in a certain order is a Finite State Machine. A state machine stores a current state, and has a nextState method, that will verify the input and move to the next state. An easy way of doing this in Java is using an enum.

We have the states

```
current state      | action                                     | next state
INITIAL            | t[1] = BTN_TOUCH &  t[2] =DOWN             | BT_TOUCH-down   
BTN_TOUCH-down     | t[1] = ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR                  | ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR
ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR | read t[1] trackingid, update MTEvent       | ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID 
ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID | read t[1] =x, update MTEvent               | ABS_MT_POSITION_X    
ABS_MT_POSITION_X  |read t[1] =y, update MTEvent                | ABS_MT_POSITION_Y   
ABS_MT_POSITION_Y  | t[1] = (mt_report)                         | SYN_MT_REPORT
SYN_MT_REPORT      | save MTEvent to event 
                   | if t[1] =(touchMajor)                      | ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR
                   | if t[1] = (synReport)                      | SYN_REPORT
SYN_REPORT         | add the event to list. 
                   | t[1]=(touchMajor)                          | ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR
                   | if t[1]=(BTN_TOUCH-up)                     | BTN_TOUCH-up
                   | if (EOF)                                   | END
BTN_TOUCH-UP       | token[1]= SYN_MT_REPORT                    | SYN_MT_REPORT
```

At each state, you check whether the input line is valid, and update the Event with data. You know at `SYN_MT_REPORT` you add the MTEvent to the Event's List and at `SYN_REPORT` you have read the whole event, so you can add the event to the event list. If the line isn't valid, have it throw a parseException that your main read loop can catch.

Based on the input, you also choose the next state, So, when you're in the `SYN_MT_REPORT` state,  when you next call parseLine, the next command could be a `ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR` or a `SYN_REPORT`, so in the nextAction method, the line read will decide between each.

- If you read the `SYN_REPORT` state, you know that you have a complete event, and to add the list of `MTEvent` in to the current `Event`
- If you read the `ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR` you know the next state will  be `ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID` for another multi-touch event.

This is how I would create the enum

```
private static enum TouchEventState {
    INITIAL{
        @Override
        public TouchEventState processLine(String line, int currentLine, Event currentEvent, List<Event> ret) throws ParseException { 
            String[] tokens = tokenize(line);
            if (validateLine(tokens)){
                return BTN_TOUCH_DOWN;
            } else {
                throw new ParseException(line, currentLine);
            }
        }

        boolean validateLine(String[] tokens){
            return tokens.length == COLS
                && tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("BTN_TOUCH") 
                &&  tokens[2].equalsIgnoreCase("DOWN");
        }
    },

    BTN_TOUCH_DOWN{
        @Override
        public TouchEventState processLine(String line,int currentLine, Event currentEvent, List<Event> ret) {
            String[] tokens = tokenize(line);
            if (validateLine(tokens){
                return ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR;
            } else {
               throw new ParseException(line, currentLine);
            }
        } 

        boolean validateLine(String[] tokens){
            return tokens.length == COLS 
            && tokens[1].equalsIgnoreCase("ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR");
        }
    },
    ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR
    {
        TouchEventState processLine(String line, int currentLine,
                Event currentEvent,MTEvent currentMtEvent, List<Event> ret) throws ParseException {
            //if valid input (you've read ,EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   00000000) do 
            //currentMtEvent.setTrackingId(000000);
        }
    },
    ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   {
        TouchEventState processLine(String line, int currentLine,
                Event currentEvent,MTEvent currentMtEvent, List<Event> ret) throws ParseException {
            //if valid input, currentMtEvent.setPosX(tokens[1]);
        }
    },
    ABS_MT_POSITION_X    {
        TouchEventState processLine(String line, int currentLine,
                Event currentEvent,MTEvent currentMtEvent, List<Event> ret) throws ParseException {
            //if valid input, currentMtEvent.setPosY(tokens[1]);
            //return ABS_MT_POSITION_Y
        }
    },
    ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    
    {
    // Read this->  EV_SYN       SYN_MT_REPORT        00000000, 
    // currentEvent.addMtEvent(currentMtEvent);
    // return SYN_MT_REPORT

    },
    SYN_MT_REPORT       {
        TouchEventState processLine(String line, int currentLine,
                Event currentEvent,MTEvent currentMtEvent, List<Event> ret) throws ParseException {
            //if valid input = SYN_REPORT   , 
            //ret.addEvent(currentEvent);

        }

    },
    SYN_REPORT           {
        TouchEventState processLine(String line, int currentLine,
                Event currentEvent,MTEvent currentMtEvent, List<Event> ret) throws ParseException {
            //if input = ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR -> currentEvent = new Event, currentMtEvent = new currentMtEvent(), return ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR 

            //if EOF return FINISH
        }

    };


 String[] tokenize(String line) {
     return line.split("\\+s");
 }
```

so your processing loop becomes

```
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
    try{
        state = state.processLine(currentLine, lineNumber, currentEvent, ret);
        ++lineNumber;
    } catch (ParseException pse) {
        // error with the input - out of sync.
        throw pse;
    }
}
return ret;
```

## Conclusion

When creating a new class I would encourage you to think about how it will be used in the rest of the System, or by another User. This leads to better naming and easier to understand code.

When parsing, a sequence, I would always use a loop to read each line of the file, then a state machine to decide what to do with that line.

Comment: The states clean the code. However, I want the events to be available in a `List`. The way you have suggested, I do not know who(where) the `MTEvent`s would be created.

Comment: Yes - change processLine method to add a currentMtEvent object. In the `ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID` state, you set the `currentMtEvent` to a new Event. In the `ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID`   
`ABS_MT_POSITION_X` and `ABS_MT_POSITION_Y` states you update the `currentMtEvent`. In the `SYN_MT_REPORT` state you add the  `currentMtEvent` to the `currentEvent`.  In the `SYN_REPORT` state you add the currentEvent to the `ret` list.

Comment: I can update the example if you wish

Comment: That would be great, and would clarify a lot.

Comment: I have added another parameter to the `processLine` method (i.e. `currentMtEvent`, i have added psuedo code to the state transitions to show how to handle them

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I have a problem with the input itself, turns out sometimes I just get the X co-ordinate or Y co-ordinate if there is no difference from the previous one and it is making parsing even more difficult.